# Mail using c code in unix box

Tags: c, unix

I used below code to send mail from my unix box. It compiled successfully.But I am not receiving any mails in mail box. Kindly help me on this. 
Do I need to do any configuration for this?

After executing the code I am seeing the some file in  /usr/spool/mail folder.
What it means actually?

```
    char cmd[100];  // to hold the command.
    char to[] = "sample@example.com"; // email id of the recepient.
    char body[] = "SO rocks";    // email body.
    char tempFile[100];     // name of tempfile.

    strcpy(tempFile,tempnam("/tmp","sendmail")); // generate temp file name.

    FILE *fp = fopen(tempFile,"w"); // open it for writing.
    fprintf(fp,"%s\n",body);        // write body to it.
    fclose(fp);             // close it.

    sprintf(cmd,"sendmail %s < %s",to,tempFile); // prepare command.
    system(cmd);     // execute it.
```

Comment: Read this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: OT: always check `fopen` returned value before to use it.